# Quarkus project failed to build

Tags: maven, jenkins, build, quarkus

I follow this quarkus guide : https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started and everything works fine on my local machine. However when I push my code and launch a jenkins build I got the following error :

```
11:19:24 [INFO] [jenkins-event-spy] Generated /home/jenkins/workspace/middleware_snapshot_develop-EKIMU4RSDFMZGBZA3XCVKQY7EEXFYGGT2UK5R5N3NP636H36IDJQ@tmp/withMavenc261dc7b/maven-spy-20200505-091643-8556196817679207068499.log
11:19:24 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project mytraindata-quarkus-test: Execution default-deploy of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.ArtifactUpload.getFileTransformer()Lorg/eclipse/aether/transform/FileTransformer;
11:19:24 [ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
11:19:24 [ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2
11:19:24 [ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
11:19:24 [ERROR] urls[0] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.8.2/maven-deploy-plugin-2.8.2.jar
11:19:24 [ERROR] urls[1] = file:/root/.m2/repository/backport-util-concurrent/backport-util-concurrent/3.1/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar
11:19:24 [ERROR] urls[2] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.11/plexus-interpolation-1.11.jar
11:19:24 [ERROR] urls[3] = file:/root/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
11:19:24 [ERROR] urls[4] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.15/plexus-utils-3.0.15.jar
11:19:24 [ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
11:19:24 [ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
11:19:24 [ERROR] 
11:19:24 [ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
11:19:24 [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
11:19:24 [ERROR] 
11:19:24 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
11:19:24 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
11:19:24 [ERROR] 
11:19:24 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
11:19:24 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
11:19:24 [ERROR] 
11:19:24 [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
11:19:24 [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :mytraindata-quarkus-test
```

Note that I have another quarkus project with the old bom which build fine:

```xml
<dependency>
                <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
```

as opposite of the new one which fails:

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-universe-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
```

I suspect that the error comes from the new bom.
Here is the configuration :

```
10:22:57 Apache Maven 3.5.3 (3383c37e1f9e9b3bc3df5050c29c8aff9f295297; 2018-02-24T19:49:05Z)
10:22:57 Maven home: /usr/share/maven
10:22:57 Java version: 1.8.0_171, vendor: Oracle Corporation
10:22:57 Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
10:22:57 Default locale: en, platform encoding: UTF-8
10:22:57 OS name: "linux", version: "3.10.0-957.21.2.el7.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

I ve installed maven 3.5.3 on my local machine and I can successfully build the project.
So I don't know what causes this failure...

Any help ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimum Maven version for newest Quarkus version is 3.6.2. Can you try upgrading to the latest Maven release?

It really looks like Maven failing due to incompatible versions.